# Leave from idle mode without using waking screen

Tags: android, android-powermanager

I'm working on a application to send data to server every 20 mins. Here i found one difficulty because of `android idle mode`. In the time of `idle mode` the network access is been disabled to the apps as mentioned [here](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/PowerManager.html#isDeviceIdleMode()). So in this time I can't able to communicate to the server. So to overcome that i found [FULL_WAKE_LOCK](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/PowerManager.html#FULL_WAKE_LOCK), which will release the device from idle mode. But actually it will wake the screen whenever we try to send data. So we don't need that. So I tried with [PARTIAL_WAKE_LOCK](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/PowerManager.html#PARTIAL_WAKE_LOCK), which will wake the cpu with the screen off. But in this time the network also disabled. So i can't able to send the data.

I searched a lot. But i haven't found any good article regard that. So Anybody could you please tell me the programmatic way to get out of idle mode without waking the screen up.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe to late.
https://stackoverflow.com/users/3049065/mahendran-sakkarai, I had a similar situation, but for a Tracking system. 
After a while all my services where in idle mode. I tried `WhiteList`, `PartialWakeLock`, not working.
`ActivityRecognition` and the `LocationServices` were down for a good while.

The solution went through register a broadcastReceiver with an Intent Filter for `PowerManager.ACTION_DEVICE_IDLE_MODE_CHANGED`
and calling `if(isDeviceIdleMode())` then `restart LocationUpdated`. This workaround forced the device to go out of idle.

Comment: Hi, I'm having the same problem. Could you add some links or detail to help elaborate? Thanks!